# Multi-line UILabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I've looked over older questions and tried all the suggestions, but still cannot seem to get a multi-line UILabel to work.  I have a UITableView and the cell is created by `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    NSString *fieldValue    = [self fieldValueAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *fieldName     = [self fieldNameAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *title         = [[self appDelegate] displayNameForFieldName:fieldName];
    Field fieldCode         = [[self appDelegate] fieldCodeForFieldName:fieldName];
    DetailCell *cell        = nil;
    NSString *identifier    = nil;

    BOOL isNotes            = [fieldName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Notes"] == NSOrderedSame;

    switch( isNotes ) {
    case NO:
    {
        identifier                  = @"DetailCell";
        cell                        = (DetailCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        NSInteger rows              = [self heightForText:fieldValue andFont:[self textFont] andWidth:cell.value.frame.size.width] / _oneRowSize.height;
        cell.value.text             = fieldValue;
        cell.name.text              = [title lowercaseString];
        cell.name.numberOfLines     = MAX( 1, rows );
        cell.value.numberOfLines    = cell.name.numberOfLines;
        break;
    }
    case YES:
    {
        cell                        = (DetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DetailCellNotes" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // cell                        = (DetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DetailCellNotes"];
        cell.value.text             = @"This is a very long line of text which should take up several lines";
        cell.name.text              = [title lowercaseString];
        cell.value.numberOfLines    = 5; // No more than 5 lines of text
        cell.value.backgroundColor  = [UIColor purpleColor];
        cell.value.lineBreakMode    = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.value.frame            = CGRectMake(cell.value.frame.origin.x, cell.value.frame.origin.y, 180, 70);
        [cell.value sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(180., 70.)];
        break;
    }
    }
cell.fieldName = fieldName;
return cell;
}
```

The height in the table view is defined like so

```
    - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
    {
        NSString *fieldName     = [self fieldNameAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGFloat height          = 0.0;

        if([fieldName isEqualToString:@"Notes"])
        {
                height = 70.;
        }
        else if([fieldName isEqualToString:@"Image"])
        {
                height = 100.;
        };

        return height;
    }
```

which makes the cell large enough to hold a 3-line label. However when the cell appears the label is only one line (shown by the background being purple).

The tableview uses prototype cells, and I've also tried to set it to numberOfLines=5 and WordWrapping, but that didn't change the effects either. I've also tried both of the commented out lines (though searches suggest that sizeToFit might actually reset numberOfLines to 1).

I wonder what I've missed. I can't see any other place where the it might be overridden.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying the label is tall but only contains one line of text, or the label is the wrong height i.e. only one line in physical height?

Comment: I think that the label is the wrong size. I put the purple background to prove that to myself. The label is only one line (colored purple) and the rest of the cell is white. Unfortunately I can't post images here until I have a higher reputation.

Comment: Could you show the full text of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation? I feel sure that this is the problem.

Comment: Seems like the frame of your label is not high enough. To make the height of the label follow/addapt according to the height of the cell, you need to either use constraints or use AutoResizingMask (which can be done in the XIB/Storyboard directly), either way telling how the label would resize when its superview resize. Another alternate solution to using constraints is to explicitly call `sizeToFit:` on `cell.value` in the code of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation instead, to force it to adjust its frame once you have set its text.

Comment: matt - I updated the code to reflect a completely working ``tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath``. It still exhibit the issue. You'll see that I also tried ``dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath``

Comment: For those following at home, I've gotten closer. @AliSoftware comment make me choose to set the constraints on that field. By pinning the Top and Bottom to the superview, I was able to get the purple background to fill the entire cell view. However I still haven't gotten it to wrap properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` to create your cell. This is a mistake, because it means that the cell has not assumed its final size. It is much better to call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. This means that the cell will actually *have* the height that you are giving it in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should then be able to set the height of the label successfully.